# SQL protect submitted data from SQL injections

Tags: php, sql

I am doing the following to protect subbmited data against sql attacks

```
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$confirm_password = stripslashes($confirm_password);
$confirm_password = mysql_real_escape_string($confirm_password);
$fullname = stripslashes($fullname);
$fullname = mysql_real_escape_string($fullname);
```

Is there an easier way of doing this? This is a registration form and i have numerous fields to protect.

Comment: Look into prepared statements (such as [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easier way of doing this?

Yes, first of all, [disable automatic slashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php), so you don't need to strip them. That will reduce the code already:

```
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$confirm_password = mysql_real_escape_string($confirm_password);
$fullname = mysql_real_escape_string($fullname);
```

If you then use so called parametrized queries, you don't need to even call `mysql_real_escape_string` any longer as well but you can just safely use the variables.

Take note that you're using the unsafe variant of `mysql_real_escape_string` because you don't provide the database link to it.

See as well: [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/367456).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use PHP's **PDO Object** (PHP Database Object) and create [prepared statements.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=YOURDB;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE id = :id';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(':id' => 25);
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

It may also help you to know you can look for a PDO Wrapper to make your life much easier.